# C# List of Tag Paths in XML File

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'd like to get all the element XPaths from a xml file, for example the xml file is,
something like when you open an XML file with Excel

```
<BookStore>
  <BookStoreInfo>
    <Address />
    <Tel />
    <Fax />
  <BookStoreInfo>
  <Book id="123" category="Science Fiction">
    <BookName />
    <ISBN />
    <PublishDate />
  </Book>
  <Book>
   ....
  </Book>
</BookStore>
```

I would like to get

```
BookStore/BookStoreInfo/Address
BookStore/BookStoreInfo/Tel
BookStore/BookStoreInfo/Fax
BookStore/Book/@id
BookStore/Book/@category
BookStore/Book/BookName
BookStore/Book/ISBN
BookStore/Book/PublishDate
```

I tried several ways, but doesn't work, how can I do it?

Comment: Would you want both `Book` elements listed identically? Given that your output doesn't include values, this seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the xml into an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and traverse through the tree until you hit a node with no children building up a string as you go and repeat.

Did a quick google to find you an example and found this right here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/847978/108847)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode of my approach:

```
calculateXPaths(curNode, stringSet, curString) {
    // This ensures only terminal nodes are counted. Remove to get all paths
    if (!curNode.hasChildren) {
        stringSet.add(curString)
    }

    foreach (attr on curNode) {
        stringSet.add(curString + "/@" + attr.name)
    }

    foreach (childNode on curNode) {
        curString = curString + "/" + childNode.name    
        calculateXPaths(childNode, stringSet, curString)
    }
}
```

You start the whole process by calling

```
calculateXPaths(xmlDocument.rootNode, new Set(), xmlDocument.rootNode.name)
```