# C# write a folder from a XML

Tags: c#, xml, path, directory

I have a XML which represents a directory tree. The file looks like this:

```
<folder name="FantasyFolders">
    <folders>
       <folder name="GlasHeim">
    </folders>
    <file>
       <file name=dog>
   </file>
</folders>
```

but with a lot of nodes

Here is the original XML to download. http://depositfiles.org/files/dicjwa5s1

I need to generate a list of for each path, like this:
Fantasy folders/Glas heim/one folfer/../file
Fantasy folder/GlasHeim/another folder/another file
I searched for similar questions in the web but i only find this one: [C# List of Tag Paths in XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140336/c-sharp-list-of-tag-paths-in-xml-file?rq=1)
Ive tried to make it by that way but still have problems.

```
public void calculatepaths(XmlNode node, string path, string CurrString)
{
    if (!node.HasChildNodes)
    {enter code here
        path = path + CurrString;
        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }
    foreach (XmlElement attr in node)
    {
    }
    foreach (XmlNode node2 in node)
    {
        path = path + "\\" + ((XmlElement)node).GetAttribute("name");
        path = path.Replace("\\\\\\", "\\\\");
        calculatepaths(node2, path, ((XmlElement)node2).GetAttribute("name"));
    }
}
```

this one is a good aproach but is not perfect because it have problems with the folders where are diferents kind of nodes (folders and files)

Thanks

The XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<folder name="FantasyFolders">
    <folders>
        <folder name="Glast Heim">
            <folders>
                <folder name="Bajando por la escalera">
                    <folders>
                        <folder name="Fondo del corredor">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Bajando la escalera">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Señor del calabozo.boss" hp="90" damage="36"
                                            defense="15" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Puerta norte">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Cadaver.txt" hp="50" damage="27" defense="11" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Puerta sur">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Cofre rojo.zip" />
                                        <file name="Suspiro.exe" hp="36" damage="35" defense="15" />
                                        <file name="Susurro.dll" hp="35" damage="37" defense="16" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                            <files>
                                <file name="Rybio.boss" hp="66" damage="29" defense="13" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                        <folder name="Puerta norte">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Hoyo en la pared">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Cofre oxidado.zip" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                            <files>
                                <file name="Experimento fallido.mp3" hp="34" damage="33"
                                    defense="6" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                        <folder name="Puerta sur">
                            <files>
                                <file name="Hombre encadenado 1.txt" hp="37" damage="21"
                                    defense="7" />
                                <file name="Hombre encadenado 2.txt" hp="37" damage="17"
                                    defense="8" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <files>
                        <file name="Cucaracha Gigante 1.avi" hp="26" damage="19"
                            defense="6" />
                        <file name="Cucaracha Gigante 2.mov" hp="31" damage="19"
                            defense="5" />
                    </files>
                </folder>
                <folder name="Puerta de la derecha">
                    <folders>
                        <folder name="Armario">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Cookieverse">
                                    <folders>
                                        <folder name="Hacia aca">
                                            <folders>
                                                <folder name="Por alla">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Cookieland">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Cofre del tesoro.zip" />
                                                                <file name="Galleta furiosa.txt" hp="80" damage="37"
                                                                    defense="20" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Galleta de soda.txt" hp="70" damage="34"
                                                            defense="16" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                                <folder name="Por Aqui">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Cookiecore">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Grandmatriarch.boss" hp="100" damage="52"
                                                                    defense="26" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Galleta magica.txt" hp="70" damage="30"
                                                            defense="17" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                            </folders>
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Galleta mutante.txt" hp="57" damage="30"
                                                    defense="14" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                        <folder name="Hacia alla">
                                            <folders>
                                                <folder name="Caliente caliente">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Cookiemore">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Baúl de galletas.zip" />
                                                                <file name="Galleta latiguda.txt" hp="80" damage="32"
                                                                    defense="20" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Galleta de chocolate.txt" hp="69" damage="30"
                                                            defense="16" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                                <folder name="Frio frio">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Cookievale">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Arbol de galletas.zip" />
                                                                <file name="Cómeme.txt" hp="76" damage="32"
                                                                    defense="20" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Galleta de mantequilla.txt" hp="69"
                                                            damage="35" defense="16" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                            </folders>
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Galleta poderosa.txt" hp="59" damage="29"
                                                    defense="13" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                    </folders>
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Galleta zombie.txt" hp="47" damage="24"
                                            defense="11" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Narnia">
                                    <folders>
                                        <folder name="Castillo de hielo">
                                            <folders>
                                                <folder name="Sala del trono">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta del norte">
                                                            <folders>
                                                                <folder name="Sala del tesoro">
                                                                    <files>
                                                                        <file name="Cofre de hielo.zip" />
                                                                    </files>
                                                                </folder>
                                                            </folders>
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Aslan.avi" hp="76" damage="42" defense="21" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                </folder>
                                            </folders>
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Golem.exe" hp="44" damage="37" defense="18" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                    </folders>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                        </folder>
                        <folder name="Puerta del fondo">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Cruzando el puente">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Executioner.exe" hp="35" damage="36" defense="16" />
                                        <file name="Mysteltainn.dll" hp="38" damage="35" defense="14" />
                                        <file name="Tyrfing.dll" hp="36" damage="33" defense="16" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Subiendo la escalera">
                                    <folders>
                                        <folder name="Fondo del corredor">
                                            <folders>
                                                <folder name="Puerta naranja">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Terraza">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Cofre mojado.zip" />
                                                                <file name="Viento del mal.dll" hp="67" damage="42"
                                                                    defense="24" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Hombre malo.mid" hp="63" damage="42"
                                                            defense="15" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                                <folder name="Puerta verde">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta este">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Alice.ppt" hp="85" damage="36" defense="20" />
                                                                <file name="Aliza.pptx" hp="87" damage="36"
                                                                    defense="21" />
                                                                <file name="Alizei.ppt" hp="89" damage="32"
                                                                    defense="20" />
                                                                <file name="Alizée.pptx" hp="87" damage="36"
                                                                    defense="21" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Chimera.avi" hp="67" damage="38" defense="18" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                                <folder name="Subiendo la escalera">
                                                    <folders>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta este">
                                                            <folders>
                                                                <folder name="Puerta adornada">
                                                                    <files>
                                                                        <file name="Payaso maligno.exe" hp="77" damage="50"
                                                                            defense="26" />
                                                                    </files>
                                                                </folder>
                                                            </folders>
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Necrófago 1.dll" hp="65" damage="43"
                                                                    defense="25" />
                                                                <file name="Necrófago 2.dll" hp="66" damage="39"
                                                                    defense="24" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta noreste">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Mago rojo.mp3" hp="74" damage="49"
                                                                    defense="18" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta noroeste">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Mago azul.mp3" hp="72" damage="49"
                                                                    defense="19" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta norte">
                                                            <folders>
                                                                <folder name="Puerta simple">
                                                                    <files>
                                                                        <file name="Mago piel.wav" hp="84" damage="50"
                                                                            defense="22" />
                                                                    </files>
                                                                </folder>
                                                            </folders>
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Mago negro.mid" hp="73" damage="45"
                                                                    defense="18" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta sudeste">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Mago rosadito.mid" hp="72" damage="44"
                                                                    defense="18" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta sur">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Mago morado.wav" hp="75" damage="47"
                                                                    defense="19" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                        <folder name="Puerta suroeste">
                                                            <files>
                                                                <file name="Otro mago azul.wav" hp="75" damage="46"
                                                                    defense="19" />
                                                            </files>
                                                        </folder>
                                                    </folders>
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Caballero del abismo.boss" hp="92"
                                                            damage="40" defense="21" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                            </folders>
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Arquero medianamente oscuro.xlsx" hp="61"
                                                    damage="29" defense="14" />
                                                <file name="Arquero no tan oscuro.xlsx" hp="64" damage="31"
                                                    defense="15" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                        <folder name="Puerta azul">
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Hombre misterioso.xlsx" hp="62" damage="29"
                                                    defense="14" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                        <folder name="Puerta violeta">
                                            <folders>
                                                <folder name="Puerta del fondo">
                                                    <files>
                                                        <file name="Criatura extraña.mov" hp="71" damage="40"
                                                            defense="18" />
                                                    </files>
                                                </folder>
                                            </folders>
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Adepto 1.ppt" hp="62" damage="26" defense="15" />
                                                <file name="Adepto 2.ppt" hp="63" damage="28" defense="15" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                    </folders>
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Arquero oscurito.xlsx" hp="48" damage="26"
                                            defense="10" />
                                        <file name="Arquero oscuro.xls" hp="50" damage="24"
                                            defense="11" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                            <files>
                                <file name="Raydric.boss" hp="80" damage="29" defense="13" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                        <folder name="Trampilla">
                            <files>
                                <file name="Cofre pequeño.zip" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <files>
                        <file name="Zombie 1.txt" hp="27" damage="17" defense="5" />
                        <file name="Zombie 2.txt" hp="29" damage="17" defense="4" />
                    </files>
                </folder>
                <folder name="Subiendo la escalera">
                    <folders>
                        <folder name="Puerta norte">
                            <files>
                                <file name="Cofre ensangrentado.zip" />
                                <file name="Fanático.doc" hp="47" damage="17" defense="8" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                        <folder name="Subiendo la escalera">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Puerta este">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Cofre sucio.zip" />
                                        <file name="Criatura con ojos desorbitados.mov" hp="51"
                                            damage="29" defense="11" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Subiendo la escalera">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Caballero sangriento.boss" hp="74" damage="34"
                                            defense="16" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                            <files>
                                <file name="Edward el vampiro.xlsx" hp="43" damage="22"
                                    defense="7" />
                                <file name="Fanático.doc" hp="50" damage="13" defense="8" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <files>
                        <file name="Novato.txt" hp="30" damage="13" defense="4" />
                        <file name="Otro zombie.txt" hp="27" damage="18" defense="5" />
                    </files>
                </folder>
                <folder name="Umbral">
                    <folders>
                        <folder name="Altar">
                            <folders>
                                <folder name="Cámara norte">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Señor Oscuro.boss" hp="82" damage="32"
                                            defense="15" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Cámara sur">
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Mosca Vampiro.ppt" hp="58" damage="20"
                                            defense="12" />
                                        <file name="Mosca Zombie 1.mov" hp="52" damage="30"
                                            defense="12" />
                                        <file name="Mosca Zombie 2.mov" hp="50" damage="30"
                                            defense="11" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                                <folder name="Detras del altar">
                                    <folders>
                                        <folder name="Hoyo en la pared">
                                            <files>
                                                <file name="Mimic.boss" hp="93" damage="43" defense="18" />
                                            </files>
                                        </folder>
                                    </folders>
                                    <files>
                                        <file name="Ilusión 1.exe" hp="34" damage="37" defense="15" />
                                        <file name="Ilusión 2.exe" hp="36" damage="27" defense="15" />
                                        <file name="Sacerdote maligno.ppt" hp="60" damage="22"
                                            defense="12" />
                                    </files>
                                </folder>
                            </folders>
                            <files>
                                <file name="Necrófago 1.doc" hp="44" damage="14" defense="8" />
                                <file name="Necrófago 2.docx" hp="59" damage="19" defense="8" />
                            </files>
                        </folder>
                    </folders>
                    <files>
                        <file name="Espectro.dll" hp="16" damage="25" defense="8" />
                    </files>
                </folder>
            </folders>
            <files>
                <file name="Zombie.txt" hp="20" damage="15" defense="1" />
            </files>
        </folder>
    </folders>
    <files>
        <file name="It's Dangerous in there.zip" />
        <file name="Take this.zip" />
    </files>
</folder>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to create the folder structure from an XML file? Or are you trying to serialize what the directory structure is into an XML file?

Comment: Im trying to create a folder structure from the XML file.

Comment: Access denied. Unable to download XML file. Can you put the file on another server?

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/453368/FantasyFolders-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to create a folder structure from the XML file.

using Linq To Xml

```
var rootDir = @"e:\temp";
var folders = XDocument.Load(filename)
                .Descendants("folder")
                .Select(x => Path.Combine(GetParents(x).Reverse().ToArray()))
                .OrderBy(x => x);

foreach(var dir in folders)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(rootDir,dir));
}
```

---

```
IEnumerable<string> GetParents(XElement x)
{
    while (x != null)
    {
        if (x.Name.LocalName == "folder") yield return x.Attribute("name").Value;
        x = x.Parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works perfect with the folders, but the files did not appear. Is there any way to create the files too?

Comment: @EnzoZerega what do you mean with  `Is there any way to create the files too`. What do you plan to write as their contents?

Comment: For the moment I only need to create a file with non contents, for example i can create in any folder the file "random.anyextension" with FileStream st = new FileStream (path\\random.anyextension, Filemode.OpenOrCreate). In the XML there are folders with files inside, each one with a specific extension (doc,zip,etc) but it does not matter the "functionality" or the contents, I only need the file as "random.anyextension".

Comment: @EnzoZerega I have already a code for this. But i am not going to post it. I don't like people asking for *turnkey* solutions without showing any effort. Is it really hard to play with my solution to get what you desire? BTW: Feel free to undo your *accept* .