# c# XML Parsing separating innerxml from innertext

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

What I am trying to do is create ideally a nested List basically a 2d list, or a 2D array if that is better for this task, that would work as follows `ID => 1 Name => Hickory`  without explicitly selecting the node.

I could use SelectNode (Woods/Wood) and then do something like `node["ID"].InnerText` but that would require that I know what the nodes name is.

Assume that this would read `wood.xml` even if there were 36 nodes instead of 7 and that I will never know the name of the nodes. I tried using `outerxml`/`innerxml` but that gives me too much information.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("wood.xml");

        //Here is wood.xml
        /*<Woods><Wood><ID>1</ID><Name>Hickory</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood><Wood><ID>2</ID><Name>Soft Maple</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood><Wood><ID>3</ID><Name>Red Oak</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood></Woods>*/


        XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

        //Display the contents of the child nodes.
        if (root.HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerXml);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

That would allow me to basically create a wood "**buffer**" if you will so I can access these values elsewhere.

Sorry if I was unclear I want to essentially make this "abstract" for lack of a better word.

So that if I were someday to change the name of "Weight" to "HowHeavy" or if i were to add an additional element "NumberOfBranches" I would not have to hardcode the structure of the xml file.

Comment: "that I will never know the name of the nodes." Then please give a sample how you would like to retrieve data.

Comment: Well that is what I don't know how to do. If I know the name of the node I could use SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText. What I am trying to accomplish is being able to read the XML file without knowing what the node names are.

Comment: @Henk about duplicates

Never really thought about that. The reason why I am trying to do this is because the project I am working on has 10 XML files, each with the same basic structure but not the same enough to make a single function to handle all things.

The problem comes in when trying to deal with a slight change in an xml file requires the edits or additions of hundreds of lines of code. So if I had a way to load the entire contents into some sort of array it would make it easier. But now I am not sure exactly how to proceed.
Slight change being the addition of a new node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you after ?

```
class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          string xml = @"<Woods><Wood><ID>1</ID><Name>Hickory</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood><Wood><ID>2</ID><Name>Soft Maple</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood><Wood><ID>3</ID><Name>Red Oak</Name><Weight>3</Weight><Thickness>4</Thickness><Density>5</Density><Purity>6</Purity><Age>7</Age></Wood></Woods>";

           XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
           //Get your wood nodes and values in a list 
           List<Tuple<string,string>> list = doc.Descendants().Select(a=> new Tuple<string,string>(a.Name.LocalName,a.Value)).ToList();

           // display the list
           list.All(a => { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Node name {0} , Node Value {1}", a.Item1, a.Item2)); return true; });
           Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. Is there any way to do it without using Linq?

Comment: @Windex yes, it is possible see 'Joshua Mills' answer , but it too verbose so enjoy Linq ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847978/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-all-elements-name-from-a-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//child::node()")`