# map an XML file's node

Tags: c#, xml, recursion

I have an XML file of depth-N. (N might vary) I want to travel all nodes and parse node names into a list of string. Basically I want to transform the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<person>
    <name></name>
    <surname></surname>
    <dateofbirth></dateofbirth>
    <phones>
        <phone>
            <countrycode></countrycode>
            <areacode></areacode>
            <number></number>
            <extension></extension>
        </phone>
        <phone>
            <countrycode></countrycode>
            <areacode></areacode>
            <number></number>
            <extension></extension>
        </phone>
    </phones>
</person>
```

into

```
person
person.name
person.surname
person.dateofbirth
person.phone.countrycode
person.phone.areacode
person.phone.number
person.phone.extension
```

Comment: I have written an unsuccessfull recursion and checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847978/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-all-elements-name-from-a-xml-file which is close to mine but still trying to understand how to adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument`. Use the following code to get the result :

```
public List<string> GetList()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    XDocument d = XDocument.Load(@"c:\text.xml");
    foreach (var name in d.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
    {
        XElement xe = (from c in d.Descendants(name.ToString()) select c).FirstOrDefault();
        string fullName = getFullName(xe, d, "");
        string[] sarr = fullName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Array.Reverse(sarr);
        string result = string.Join(".", sarr);
        result.Add(result);
    }
}
private string getFullName(XElement elem, XDocument doc, string prevName)
{
    if (elem.Parent == null)
    {
        prevName += "." + elem.Name.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        prevName += "." + getFullName(elem.Parent, doc, elem.Name.ToString());
    }

    return prevName;
}
```